# C++ binary tree pointers issue

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

So i'm making a simple binary tree to store integers but I keep getting a "expression must have pointer-to-class type" error in the insert function, this is probably just me not noticing something obvious but I'm relatively new to C++ so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
struct node
{
    //Data stored in this node of the tree
    int data;
    //The left branch of the tree
    node *left;
    //The right branch of the tree
    node *right;
};

using namespace std;

//Inserts a value into the tree
void insert(node **tree, int value)
{
    if (*tree == nullptr)
    {
        //Create new node
        *tree = new node;
        //Set new value
        (*tree)->data = value;
        //Set branches to nullptr
        (*tree)->left = nullptr;
        (*tree)->right = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        if (value < (*tree)->data)
            insert(*tree->left, value);//ERROR HERE
        if (value >(*tree)->data)
            insert(*tree->right, value);//ERROR HERE
    }
}

//Deletes the tree
void delete_tree(node *tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
        delete_tree(tree->left);
        delete_tree(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
}

//Prints the tree in order
void inorder(node *tree)
{
    if (tree != nullptr)
    {
            inorder(tree->left);
            cout << tree->data << " ";
            inorder(tree->right);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (true){
        //if(userinputflag=0)
        //else node *tree = input number
        node *tree = nullptr;

        while (true)
        {
            int num;
            cout << "Enter number (-1 to exit): ";
            cin >> num;

            if (num == -1)
                break;
            insert(&tree, num);
        }

        inorder(tree);
        cout << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `insert(&((*tree)->left), value);` already?

Comment: You should remove the irrelevant code *before* posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `insert` is:

```
void insert(node **tree, int value);
```

You are passing in `*tree->left`, which is `*(tree->left)`, which is not a valid expression because `tree` is not a "pointer-to-class type", as the error suggests (it's a pointer-to-pointer-to-class).

What you had intended was `(*tree)->left`, which is a valid expression, but that would be a `node*` and our signature calls for a `node**`, hence:

```
insert(&((*tree)->left), value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You function as first parameter requier pointer-to-pointer to node

```
void insert(node **tree, int value)
```

And here

```
insert(*tree->left, value);//ERROR HERE
```

which is not a valid.

I think you need something like this

```
insert(&((*tree)->left), value);//ERROR HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert(*tree->left, value)
```

Operator `->` has a higher precedence than `*`. The expression `tree->left` is syntactically wrong as `tree` type in the expression is `node **`. So, try -

```
insert(&((*tree)->left), value)
```